# Vulkan library injection issue

Tags: vulkan

I'm working on a Vulkan application (that has nothing to do with OBS).. and I have strange messages and unexpected crash

```
[OBS] OBS_CreateDevice: texture sharing is not supported
[OBS] Failed to open pipe
[OBS] graphics-hook.dll loaded against process: coffeecupd.exe
[OBS] (half life scientist) everything.. seems to be in order
```

Seems like obs is injecting something in my code..how can I isolate my Vulkan application?

Of course, I'm puzzled as OBS is shut down while this happens

Comment: OBS is a recording software. It is its job to inject into **every** app. If you don't want it, then uninstall it.

Comment: I have same message in my vulkan sandbox but everything works correct. Will be happy to find some way to disable hooks when OBS is shut down.

Comment: @krOoze for your information..OBS was obviously shut down when I tested

Comment: Doesn't matter whether it is shutdown or not. The dll is injected in every executable the windows starts. Otherwise obviously you could only record apps that you started after OBS.

Comment: Did you find the cause for your crash? I experience the same thing. Tested on Intel and AMD GPU. The OBS stuff has not been the error source. I get an access violation at the vulkan dll when calling vkCreateGraphicsPipelines()